# Trouble running serverless React app on Windows 11

Tags: reactjs, windows, react-native, npm, yarnpkg

Environment: Windows 11, WSL2, VSCode

App: https://mui.com/store/items/berry-react-material-admin-free/

The app runs fine when using npm/yarn start, however, I'm attempting to run it serverless on my PC.

I ran the build command (tried both npm and yarn), and opened the index.html in the build folder but the page never loads. I've tried editing the package.json to reflect both the relative and full paths. I also edited app.js to use HashRouter, but still no luck. Checking the Chrome developer tools shows no errors in the console, and all 200's in the network tab.

app:

```
import Routes from 'routes';
import { HashRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
...

 const App = () => {
    const customization = useSelector((state) => state.customization);

    return (
        <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
            <ThemeProvider theme={themes(customization)}>
                <CssBaseline />
                <NavigationScroll>
                    <Router>
                        <Routes />
                    </Router>
                </NavigationScroll>
            </ThemeProvider>
        </StyledEngineProvider>
    );
};
```

package.json:

```
{
 "name": "berry-material-react-free",
    "version": "3.2.0",
    "private": true,
    "homepage": "./",
    "dependencies":{ ....}
...
}
```